# Is it possible to get a rangeOfString from a group of items in an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2, nsrange

What i've tried was using a for-in loop, however that just cycles to the last value and gives me the rangeOfString for that value. It would be a lot to write the rangeOfString for all the values i want but if needed I don't mind. I just wanted to know if it was possible to use an array instead.

```
while true {
        let attempts = ["hello","goodbye"]
        for attempt in attempts{

             tru = attempt




        let range = text.rangeOfString("hello", options: [], range: searchRange)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`:

```
let text: NSString = "hello goodbye"
let attempts = ["hello", "goodbye"]
let ranges = attempts.map { text.rangeOfString($0, options: NSStringCompareOptions(rawValue: 0)) }
```